# A special inequality (related to 2021)

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $x,y,z\in[0,1]$ such that: $$x+y+z\leq 1+2xyz$$

I want to prove the following inequality (for a student in high school):

$$x^{2021}+y^{2021}+z^{2021}\leq 1+2\sqrt{xyz}^{2021}$$

---

**Edit:**

This question was sent to me by a student from high school, his teacher ask them to look for proof. I think it's a kind of question given in "International Mathematical Olympiad", that's why the "2021" number is used here. I tried by recurrence..

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Also, please provide context

Comment: As $2021$ does not seem to possess special properties relevant to this problem, I bet that other exponents will work.

Comment: Is it $(xyz)^{2021/2}$ or $(xyz)^{1/2021}$ in the right-hand side?

Comment: @Mindlack The first one, as I write it

Comment: It looks like AM-GM and/or Cauchy-Schwarz, isn't it?

Comment: Numerically the following seems true, but I don't know how to prove it: If $$f(n,x,y,z)\overset{\text{Def.}}=1+(xyz)^{\frac n2}-x^n-y^n-z^n,$$ then for all $x,y,z\in[0,1]$, $$f(1,x,y,z)\ge 0$$ implies that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(n, x,y,z)\ge 0$$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality is true. However, the only proof I know has nothing to do with high school nor IMO mathematics...

For $x,y,z \in [0,1]$, let $u = \sqrt{x}, v = \sqrt{y}, w = \sqrt{z}$. We have $1 - u^2, 1 - v^2, 1 - w^2 \ge 0$.

Together with
$$\left|\begin{matrix}1 & u & v\\ u & 1 & w\\ v & w & 1\end{matrix}\right| = 1-u^2-v^2-w^2+2uvw \ge 1 - x - y - z + 2xyz \ge 0$$
[Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) tells us the matrix $M =\begin{bmatrix}1 & u & v\\ u & 1 & w\\ v & w & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semi-definite.

For any integer $n > 1$, [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) tell us the $n$-fold [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of $M$ with itself is positive semi-definite. By Sylvester's criterion again, we find

$$1 - u^{2n} - v^{2n} - w^{2n} + 2(uvw)^n =
\left|\begin{matrix}1 & u^n & v^n\\ u^n & 1 & w^n\\ v^n & w^n & 1\end{matrix}\right| \ge 0$$
Substitute $n$ by $2021$, the desired inequality follows.

Comment: (+1) It is nice, although (as you also said) perhaps not appropriate for "This question was sent to me by a student from high school".

Comment: very nice solution with the application of linear algebra! +1

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative proof**:

Let us prove that, for any integer $n \ge 2$,
$$x^n + y^n + z^n \le 1 + 2 \sqrt{xyz}^n.$$

Let
$$f(n) = 1 + 2\sqrt{xyz}^n - x^n - y^n - z^n.$$
We have
$$f(n + 1) - f(n) = 2\sqrt{xyz}^{n + 1} - x^{n + 1} - y^{n + 1} - z^{n + 1} - 2\sqrt{xyz}^n + x^n + y^n + z^n,$$
and
\begin{align*}
 &[f(n + 2) - f(n + 1)] - [f(n + 1) - f(n)]\\
 =\,\, & 2\sqrt{xyz}^n (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^2
 - x^n(1 - x)^2 - y^n(1 - y)^2 - z^n(1 - z)^2\\
 \le\,\,& 2\sqrt{xyz}^n (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^2 - 
 3\sqrt[3]{x^n(1 - x)^2 \cdot y^n(1 - y)^2 \cdot z^n(1 - z)^2}\\
 =\,\,& (xyz)^{n/3}
 \left[2(xyz)^{n/6} (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^2 - 3\sqrt[3]{(1 - x)^2(1 - y)^2(1 - z)^2}\right]\\
 \le\,\,& (xyz)^{n/3}
 \left[2(xyz)^{2/6} (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^2 - 3\sqrt[3]{(1 - x)^2(1 - y)^2(1 - z)^2}\right]\\
 \le\,\,& (xyz)^{n/3}
 \left[2(xyz)^{2/6} (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^2 - 2\sqrt[3]{(1 - x)^2(1 - y)^2(1 - z)^2}\right]\\
 \le\,\,& 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(The proof of (1) is given at the end.)

Thus, we have
$$f(n + 2) - f(n + 1) \le f(n + 1) - f(n), \quad \forall n \ge 2.$$
Also, clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty} [f(n + 1) - f(n)]  = 0$.
Thus, we have
$$f(n + 1) - f(n) \ge 0, \quad \forall n\ge 2.$$

Also, we have
$f(2) = 1 + 2xyz - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \ge 1 + 2xyz - x - y - z \ge 0$.

Thus,
$$f(n) \ge f(2) \ge 0, \quad \forall n \ge 2.$$

We are done.

---

---

*Proof of (1)*:

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{xyz} (1 - \sqrt{xyz})^3 \le (1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z).$$

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.
We have $1 + 2r \ge p$.

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z)\\
 =\,\,& 1 - xyz + (xy + yz + zx) - (x + y + z)\\
 =\,\,& 1 - r + q - p\\
 \ge\,\,& 1 - r + \sqrt{3pr} - p\\
 =\,\,& 1 - r - \left(\sqrt{p} - \frac12\sqrt{3r}\right)^2 + \frac34 r\\
 \ge\,\,& 1 - r - \left(\sqrt{1 + 2r} - \frac12\sqrt{3r}\right)^2 + \frac34 r
\end{align*}
where we have used $1 + 2r \ge p$ and $\sqrt{p} \ge \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3r}$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{r} (1 - \sqrt{r})^3 \le 1 - r - \left(\sqrt{1 + 2r} - \frac12\sqrt{3r}\right)^2 + \frac34 r$$
or
$$\sqrt{r}\left(\sqrt{3 + 6r} - 1 - 3r + r\sqrt{r}\right)\ge 0$$
which is true (using $r\in [0, 1]$).

We are done.

Comment: +1 nice to have something more elementary.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. However, it is quite complicated. Perhaps there is a simple proof using e.g. AM-GM etc.

Comment: @River Note that numerically the following seems true, but I don't know how to prove it: If $$f(n,x,y,z)\overset{\text{Def.}}=1+(xyz)^{\frac n2}-x^n-y^n-z^n,$$ then for all $x,y,z\in[0,1]$, $$f(1,x,y,z)\ge 0$$ implies that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(n, x,y,z)\ge 0$$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I think it is true. Perhaps you may prove $f''(n) \le 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f'(n) = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks for you all, you did a great job!